# Add li element around every second <span> tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

don't know if this is possible ..
I want to add a li element to every second span-tag.
My HTML look like that:

```
<span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>

<span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>

<span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>

<span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>
```

At the end, it should look like this:

```
<li>
    <span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>

    <span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>
</li>
<li>  
    <span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>
    <span class="article_item"><img src="images/container_item.jpg" /><h2><a href="">Nokia Connecting N97</a></h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu mattis lectus.</p></span>
</li>
```

Any Ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean every 2 span tags, not every second span tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) and [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) in a loop, like this:

```
var spans = $("span.article_item");
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i+=2) {
  spans.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<li />");
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cr3pW/), be sure to do something like this at the end, since `<li>` elements need a parent:

```
$("li").wrapAll("<ul />");
```